# How can I close Chrome window visiting specific URL through a batch script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a piece of third-party software and every time a call comes it executes a batch file that I control the content of.

My desired functionality is to load http://example.com/popup.php via Chrome after killing all other Chrome windows with http://example.com/popup.php open. I don't want the user to have to keep closing them.

```
tasklist /V /FI "*popup.php*"
start "popup.php" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="data:text/html,<html><body><script>window.moveTo(600,200);window.resizeTo(700,600);window.location='http://example.com/popup.php';</script></body></html>"
```

As you can see above I'm attempting to close all chrome instances that are currently visiting http://example.com/popup.php and then loading a new one.

However, this solution does not work because the URL is not part of the window title from what I can see so tasklist doesn't find it.

What are my options here? Ideally, this would be in a batch file but if not Powershell might work.

Thanks :-)

Comment: did you take a look at this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36849681/8953000 the accepted solution might work for you since you control the source that opens the window.

Comment: taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq popup.php". Accidentally put in tasklist, what a n00b I am.